# Teamcity variable replacement in nuspec file

Tags: nuget-package, teamcity-7.0

This is my nuspec file to get the package generated from teamcity. The version is actualy set by the teamcity variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Company.Name</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>Title</title>
    <authors>My Name</authors>
    <owners>We are the owners</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Support</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>Core</tags>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Core.Assembly" version="[1.0.$teamcity.build.id$]" />   
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

How would I replace the version with the current teamcity build id number? Tried with both `$teamcity.build.id$`  and `%teamcity.build.id%`

This did not work. I tried with `$version$` as well. The version gets correctly replaced in the version tag of the package, but not on the dependency.

I want to use the same version of the package that is in the current build, so they have the same build number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolved with AssemblyInfo patcher  from Teamcity Build Features.

To fix,

Configuration Steps -> Build Steps -> Add Build Feature (Button)

Add **AssemblyInfo Patcher** and give the version to 1.0.%teamcity.build.id% and that resolved the problem.

Having the dependent libraries at the version with the $version$ resolved it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to replace it via TeamCity variables. Use the -version switch, something like:

```
nuget.exe pack <nuspec> -version %teamcity.build.id%
```

This way the nuspec version will be overridden at runtime.

Comment: Dependent Libraries need to be of the same version. Resolved with Assembly Patcher.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by simply putting [$version$] in my dependency.

Comment: AssemblyInfo Patcher versions your dll as well. Otherwise dll will be on one version and nuget package will be on another version.

Comment: This worked for me. The key is to make sure the `-Version` switch is used on the `nuget pack` command.

Answer (score 3):

In TeamCity 9.1 You can override the version number in the "Nuget Pack" build step.

[image]

Comment: This may be cumbersome to configure if you want to have same versions across all projects. Means you need to configure for each nuspec instead of one centralized location.